# Почему контейнер получает ip (docker0) шлюза вместо ip клиента?

Tags: сеть, iptables, docker

Я запустил coreos-vagrant образ системы и контейнер с Nginx.
Почему Nginx получает ip шлюза а не реальный ip клиента?

Пример лога Nginx:

```
172.17.8.1 - - [17/Aug/2016:09:18:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-"
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
    Chrome/51.0.27 04.84 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

При этом на домашней ubuntu ip адреса отображаются корректно.

Пробовал запускать с разными флагами `--iptables=false` и `--userland-proxy=false`. Сравнивал настройки docker network на Ubuntu и CoreOS, отличий не заметил.

P.S. Я так понимаю в CoreOS запросы к контейнеру идут через дефолтный gateway, который меняет адрес отправителя. Тепереь вопрос - что нужно поправить в правилах маршрутизации, что бы этого не происходило?

P.S. Добавил информацию по `tcpdump` и `ip route show table main`
Более полное описание: https://gist.github.com/batazor/3d1695645b0c9abb7649b1281cbf4f7f

**ip route show table main**

**CoreOS**

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  proto dhcp  src 10.0.2.15  metric 1024 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15 
10.0.2.2 dev eth0  proto dhcp  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 1024 
172.17.8.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.8.101 
172.18.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.18.0.1
```

**Nginx container**

```
default via 172.18.0.1 dev eth0 
172.18.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.18.0.3
```

**TCPdump**

**ping из CoreOS к Nginx Container**

```
14:18:08.984025 IP 172.18.0.1 > 73440c96b5d9: ICMP echo request, id 20328, seq 1, length 64
14:18:08.984049 IP 73440c96b5d9 > 172.18.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 20328, seq 1, length 64
```

**С хостовой Ubuntu `curl ip_virtualbox_coreos:ip_nginx`**

**tcpdump -i eth1**

```
13:58:15.165408 IP 172.17.8.1.46004 > core-01.ddi-tcp-1: Flags [S], seq 2732400208, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 10312063 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:58:15.165564 IP core-01.ddi-tcp-1 > 172.17.8.1.46004: Flags [S.], seq 3456357314, ack 2732400209, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 5941835 ecr 10312063,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:58:15.165902 IP 172.17.8.1.46004 > core-01.ddi-tcp-1: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10312063 ecr 5941835], length 0
13:58:15.166046 IP 172.17.8.1.46004 > core-01.ddi-tcp-1: Flags [P.], seq 1:82, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10312063 ecr 5941835], length 81
13:58:15.166071 IP core-01.ddi-tcp-1 > 172.17.8.1.46004: Flags [.], ack 82, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 5941836 ecr 10312063], length 0
13:58:15.166218 IP core-01.ddi-tcp-1 > 172.17.8.1.46004: Flags [P.], seq 1:239, ack 82, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 5941836 ecr 10312063], length 238
13:58:15.166264 IP core-01.ddi-tcp-1 > 172.17.8.1.46004: Flags [P.], seq 239:851, ack 82, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 5941836 ecr 10312063], length 612
13:58:15.166558 IP 172.17.8.1.46004 > core-01.ddi-tcp-1: Flags [.], ack 239, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 10312064 ecr 5941836], length 0
13:58:15.166570 IP 172.17.8.1.46004 > core-01.ddi-tcp-1: Flags [.], ack 851, win 247, options [nop,nop,TS val 10312064 ecr 5941836], length 0
```

**tcpdump -i docker0**

```
13:57:36.192668 IP 172.17.8.1.45990 > 172.18.0.3.http: Flags [S], seq 2796265064, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 10302320 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:57:36.192763 IP 172.18.0.3.http > 172.17.8.1.45990: Flags [S.], seq 1432538445, ack 2796265065, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 5902862 ecr 10302320,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:57:36.193383 IP 172.17.8.1.45990 > 172.18.0.3.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10302320 ecr 5902862], length 0
13:57:36.193730 IP 172.17.8.1.45990 > 172.18.0.3.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:82, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10302320 ecr 5902862], length 81: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
13:57:36.193748 IP 172.18.0.3.http > 172.17.8.1.45990: Flags [.], ack 82, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 5902863 ecr 10302320], length 0
13:57:36.193897 IP 172.18.0.3.http > 172.17.8.1.45990: Flags [P.], seq 1:239, ack 82, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 5902864 ecr 10302320], length 238: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
13:57:36.194087 IP 172.17.8.1.45990 > 172.18.0.3.http: Flags [.], ack 239, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 10302321 ecr 5902864], length 0
13:57:36.194100 IP 172.18.0.3.http > 172.17.8.1.45990: Flags [P.], seq 239:851, ack 82, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 5902864 ecr 10302321], length 612: HTTP
13:57:36.195635 IP 172.17.8.1.45990 > 172.18.0.3.http: Flags [.], ack 851, win 247, options [nop,nop,TS val 10302321 ecr 5902864], length 0
13:57:36.195869 IP 172.17.8.1.45990 > 172.18.0.3.http: Flags [F.], seq 82, ack 851, win 247, options [nop,nop,TS val 10302321 ecr 5902864], length 0
13:57:36.195914 IP 172.18.0.3.http > 172.17.8.1.45990: Flags [F.], seq 851, ack 83, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 5902866 ecr 10302321], length 0
13:57:36.196099 IP 172.17.8.1.45990 > 172.18.0.3.http: Flags [.], ack 852, win 247, options [nop,nop,TS val 10302321 ecr 5902866], length 0
```

**Из самого Nginx Container `tcpdump -i eth0`**

```
14:00:05.379097 IP 172.17.8.1.46016 > 73440c96b5d9.http: Flags [S], seq 1048090505, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 10339617 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:00:05.379167 IP 73440c96b5d9.http > 172.17.8.1.46016: Flags [S.], seq 3922645363, ack 1048090506, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 6052049 ecr 10339617,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:00:05.379658 IP 172.17.8.1.46016 > 73440c96b5d9.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10339617 ecr 6052049], length 0
14:00:05.379664 IP 172.17.8.1.46016 > 73440c96b5d9.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:82, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10339617 ecr 6052049], length 81
14:00:05.379711 IP 73440c96b5d9.http > 172.17.8.1.46016: Flags [.], ack 82, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 6052049 ecr 10339617], length 0
14:00:05.380200 IP 73440c96b5d9.http > 172.17.8.1.46016: Flags [P.], seq 1:239, ack 82, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 6052050 ecr 10339617], length 238
14:00:05.380265 IP 73440c96b5d9.http > 172.17.8.1.46016: Flags [P.], seq 239:851, ack 82, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 6052050 ecr 10339617], length 612
14:00:05.380696 IP 172.17.8.1.46016 > 73440c96b5d9.http: Flags [.], ack 239, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 10339617 ecr 6052050], length 0
14:00:05.380702 IP 172.17.8.1.46016 > 73440c96b5d9.http: Flags [.], ack 851, win 247, options [nop,nop,TS val 10339617 ecr 6052050], length 0
14:00:05.380834 IP 172.17.8.1.46016 > 73440c96b5d9.http: Flags [F.], seq 82, ack 851, win 247, options [nop,nop,TS val 10339617 ecr 6052050], length 0
14:00:05.380969 IP 73440c96b5d9.http > 172.17.8.1.46016: Flags [F.], seq 851, ack 83, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 6052051 ecr 10339617], length 0
14:00:05.381648 IP 172.17.8.1.46016 > 73440c96b5d9.http: Flags [.], ack 852, win 247, options [nop,nop,TS val 10339617 ecr 6052051], length 0
14:00:05.791231 IP 73440c96b5d9.46719 > 10.0.2.3.domain: 27086+ PTR? 1.8.17.172.in-addr.arpa. (41)
14:00:05.801673 IP 10.0.2.3.domain > 73440c96b5d9.46719: 27086 NXDomain 0/0/0 (41)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. С помощью `tcpdump` определите, что происходит с запросами.
2. Проверьте, распространяется это только на HTTP-запросы или на весь трафик (например, на ICMP).
3. В зависимости от результатов, полученных в 1 и 2, нужно настраивать соответствующие подсистемы (уточните результаты в вопросе и я допишу, что делать дальше).

Comment: Постарался добавить информацию по tcpdump